# Как отправить SID используя Set-Cookie через POST?

Tags: post, cookie, axios

Всем привет.получил тестовое задание,но никак не пойму первый пункт)
Значение SID  я получил из cookie,но как его можно передать через post используя set-cookie?

Работа с REST API lichi.com с использованием Axios (обязательно).

1. При выполнении первого запроса, необходимо сохранить значение SID из cookie и обязательно
   передавать при всех последующих запросах используя Set-Cookie.
   Сохранение SID позволит серверу идентифицировать Вас как единичного пользователя
2. Необходимо выполнить запрос на добавления товара в корзину
   Адрес: https://api.lichi.com/cart/add
   Метод: POST
   Параметры: lang=1, shop=1, id=(88250 | 88248 | 88249 | 88247)

Comment: Этот тест на знание протокола? Какой такой Set-Cookie в запросе?

Comment: Сам не понимаю

Comment: Set-cookie это же про ответ с сервера,никак не про запрос

Comment: Ну так пойти к авторам задания и уточнить чего же они хотят. И вообще дело происходит в браузере или на сервере?

Comment: в браузере так как попросили сделать с использованием React и вакансия на фронт

Comment: Тогда задание ещё более непонятно. Обычно с сохранением и отправкой кук  браузер успешно справляется сам.

Comment: В общем уточняйте задание.